# How to use flash without stopping camera feed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, computer-vision, android-camera

I am currently working on a barcode scanning app, which uses the mobile vision api for the majority of processes. I am trying to implement a flash button so that a user may scan in low light, but for some reason the activation of flash freezes the camera feed. Is there some way to start flash with a button while the feed is active? To activate flash without interfering with other threads? Thanks!

Comment: you should add some code, to show what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this code in my custom camera Application.when User clicks the FlashOn Button then Flash will be start.i think this code will help to you.

try this code (OnButton Click) :

```
private void btnFlashOnClick() {

if (mCamera != null) {
                // First get the Camera Parameters.
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

                // set FlashMode to camera parameters.
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                // set Parameters Objects to Camera.
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

                // Finally, Start the Preview Of a Camera
                mCamera.startPreview(); // this Line is Usefull for MyApp.If you don't need then Remove this Line.
            }
}
```

this code is works fine in my App..Hope this will helps you...(:

Comment: Thanks Great! This Was Very Helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what camera api you are using as there are few.

[CameraManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html) has 
`void setTorchMode (String cameraId, boolean enabled)`
 that lets you operate flash regardless of current state of the camera (and without a need to restart one), but it could be overridden by other apps too