# How to keep focus of android camera2?

Tags: android, autofocus, android-camera2

I am trying to take 6 photos by rotating my phone for each 60 degree using camera2 api.
First time I need to take first photo using autofocus when focus area is the center of my screen. 
And I have to keep this focus for the next 5 photos, it should not try to get new focus.
I have been trying to make it for a week. But the results are not as expected. I tried many ways and I faced few problems: images are blurry, the camera tries to find new focus for each photos, and so on.

It would be great if someone shows me direction :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exact answer of your question..but i will try to tell you something's about your Question.

[How to use flash without stopping camera feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419393/how-to-use-flash-without-stopping-camera-feed/41421498#41421498)

above is link of my Answer.check that

i think ,in your App you have to put some condition for that.

Set your Flash mode regarding Rotation or whatever as you want..Like whenever Your Rotation is this, then Your Flash will this.
Like [On,Auto,Flash].

Hope this will help you...(:

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However I should not use flash it will effect to the stitching all photos together and also I am using camera2 api.

Comment: Ok Bro. @MuhridinIbragimov i understand.